# Presence of cross stratified conglomerates in fan deltas

Tags: geology, sedimentology, waves, tides

Why are cross stratified conglomerates found in deposits of fan deltas? I know that fan deltas are alluvial fans that deposit directly into the sea, hence they are poorly sorted.But could not understand the reason for presence of cross stratified conglomerates.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: are you talking about cross bedding? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-bedding

Comment: It is typical in a delta to find cross bedding, and stratified sediments with a grainsize function of the flow event (seasonal flood, recession) or a stream getting a new flow path - so,  fine to coarse alternations are common. Conglomerate is non-sorted. So you have a layer of conglomerate? And what above/under?